# I am trying to have a simple toogle on checkbox change but it's only showing. What is issue?

Tags: angular, typescript, toggle

I am trying to do a div toggle on checkbox change event but it's not working (it's only showing the div but not hiding on uncheck). What is issue?

html

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="subCheckboxClicked()"> Show/Hide

<div *ngIf="isSubBatchEdit" class="mb-3">
  <strong>Edit Sub Impacts</strong>      
</div>
```

ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  isSubBatchEdit = false;

  subCheckboxClicked() {
    this.isSubBatchEdit = true;
  };
}
```

https://angular-ivy-5q3gjd.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
subCheckboxClicked() {
    this.isSubBatchEdit = !this.isSubBatchEdit;
  };
```

Or better use [(ngModel)]

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isSubBatchEdit"> Show/Hide

<div *ngIf="isSubBatchEdit" class="mb-3">
  <strong>Edit Sub Impacts</strong>      
</div>
```

See that in this last one you only need declare a variable

```
isSubBatchEdit:boolen=false
```

Yes, Angular work relation variables in .ts with what we see in the .html (relation model with view)